Anaconda navigator installation in Mac Pro M3
I am installing for the first time Anaconda Navigator in Apple Mac Pro M3 (Purchased from you) but the installer is not getting downloaded.
I have selected an apple chip gui installer.
Once I click the installer the following message is coming
{
"reasons": "terms of service rate limit exceeded"
"message": "It has been determined that you are in violation of the anaconda terms of the service, and may not be licensed for usage."

}

Please do the needful
The installer is not getting download

Seems to be a widespread issue right now https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/cant-download-anaconda-say-violating-terms-of-service/76074/1

And I'm quite sure you didn't purchase it from us... so did you post this accidentally here instead of actual end user support?

I'm getting the same error, so this might be a temporary error on the server side.
